# How can we create custom capability for a member group so that we can check in our module and give access to it

Tags: members, control-panel, module

I am creating a module for a simple form submission. In admin, I am showing a table view of all entries. I have a specific member group "pitch" who can access only that module. In addition they can't access the "Export in CSV" functionality for listing. But super admin can do all things.

1. How can I create a custom privilege for "pitch" member group so that they can't access "Export" button.
2. OR hide button if "pitch" member login in CP
3. How can we do this through module?
4. Please provide a reference url or a piece of code.

Comment: Umm.. Your question is pretty unclear. "access" really doesn't make sense... Are you actually referring to member group privileges? Please clean up your question and grammar and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Here's your first reference URL: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd love to try and help you! Please edit your question and be more verbose in what you've done (do you already have a custom module in place?) and examples of what your looking to accomplish.

Comment: So this is Control Panel related? Avinash, please **edit** your question, don't add comments to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the add on [CP CSS & JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) to hide the button with CSS as you already suggest yourself. I know there are options to check for member privileges in add-ons but I don't know them off the top of my head.

Edit:

You could use this code in your module. [More info](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html):

```
if (ee()->session->userdata('group_id') == 1)
{
    exit('A Superadmin');
}
```

Comment: Hi Balloonatic, we can't use group id as Its a static id. we need to check privilege like 'can_export_data' or 'can_edit' like this. so that we can use it in general. Is it possible in expression engine to give such privilege to group member during creating new one and check it in our template?

Comment: In EE you can give members access to modules, but not to specific module functions as far as I know. That is something you would have to code yourself. I would make a view where all member groups are shown and an option to register which privilege each group has.